# Как удалить строку из базы данных, имея значения ячеек в QTableView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview, qtsql

Смог вытащить значения ячеек с `QTableView`, назначив их переменными. 
Теперь, зная переменные, нужно удалить из базы данных строки, содержащие эти значения (имени и фамилии в данном случае). 
Какой метод надо использовать?

**main.py**

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *

    
conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 435)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 170, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        #        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: 
        self.add_disp())
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 591, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))

        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_surname = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_date = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Surname:', self.line_edit_surname)
        form_layout.addRow('Date:', self.line_edit_date)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_disp)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.delete_disp)

        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase.
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются 
        здесь.
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')

        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, которое будет 
        использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);
        db.setDatabaseName('todo.db')

        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False.
        db.open()

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(),
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("disp_list")  # !!! тавлица в db

        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)

    def add_disp(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        surname = inputDialog.line_edit_surname.text()
        date = inputDialog.line_edit_date.text()
        if not name or not surname or not date:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return

        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("disp_name", name)
        r.setValue("disp_surname", surname)
        r.setValue("disp_date", date)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

    def delete_disp(self):
        pass

        row = self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row()
        col = self.tableWidget.currentIndex().column()

        print("row={}, col={}".format(row, col))
        print("tableWidget->      {}".format(self.tableWidget))
        print("tableWidget.model->{}".format(self.tableWidget.model()))
        name_del = "tableWidget.model.data.currentIndex        -> {}".format(
            self.tableWidget.model().data(self.tableWidget.currentIndex()))
        surname_del = "tableWidget.model.index.index(row, 0).data -> {}".format(self.tableWidget.model().index(row, 1).data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил для вас метод удаления записи из БД, проверьте.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


'''
conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
'''


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 435)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 170, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: 
#        self.add_disp())

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 591, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)




    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))

        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))




class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_surname = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_date = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Surname:', self.line_edit_surname)
        form_layout.addRow('Date:', self.line_edit_date)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_disp)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.delete_disp)


        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase.
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь.
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')

        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, 
        # которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);
        db.setDatabaseName('todo.db')

        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False.
        db.open()

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(),
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("disp_list")  # !!! тавлица в db

        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)


    def add_disp(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        surname = inputDialog.line_edit_surname.text()
        date = inputDialog.line_edit_date.text()
        if not name or not surname or not date:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return

        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("disp_name", name)
        r.setValue("disp_surname", surname)
        r.setValue("disp_date", date)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#     Удалить запись   
    def delete_disp(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите запись для удаления.')
            return    

        name = self.model.record(row).value(1)
        surname = self.model.record(row).value(2)
        date = self.model.record(row).value(3)
        
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        inputDialog.setWindowTitle('Удалить запись ???')
        inputDialog.line_edit_name.setText(name)
        inputDialog.line_edit_surname.setText(surname)
        inputDialog.line_edit_date.setText(date)       
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  

        self.model.removeRow(self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row())      # !!!         
        self.model.select()                                              # !!!
        
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Успех', 'Запись удалена.')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick, благодарю за ответ еще раз, вы мне уже помогали на днях, и этот ваш метод выше я тоже смотрел на стаке сегодня на похожем вопросе.  А так, как я хочу,  получится сделать или это будет некорректно и так не делают?

Comment: @stan_88 я написал вам как это правильно делать. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и как полезный, если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому. Если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Спасибо, возьму ваш метод за базу!

Comment: @stan_88 пожалуйста. Данные хранятся в БД - это модель, то что вы видите в окне tableWidget - это  представление. Если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому, вы также можете отмечать мои ответы и как полезные.